MTLBuffer didModifyRange not required
I think the MTLBuffer method didModifyRange is not required on my computer (late 2013 macbook, IntelHD4000 graphics card). Why is this the case? In what cases will it be required?
Is it because this GPU uses system memory, so the CPU and GPU are always synchronized? Or does it sometimes just work without it, but in general it is required?
Documentation says this is required for MTLResourceModeManaged. But I have removed the didModifyRange call and in many situations nothing changes.

A managed buffer is implemented differently on Intel, AMD and Apple Silicon GPUs. Apple Silicon and Intel GPUs use unified memory, which means that the physical memory location for the MTLBuffer in CPU and GPU match. That is not the case with AMD GPUs. On AMD GPUs (and on other discrete GPUs in general, other APIs have similar concept) you can think of "managed" buffers as two separate physical locations for memory, one for CPU and one for GPU. And the driver is responsible for making sure they are coherent, meaning that the changes in GPU contents of the buffer are visible to CPU and vice versa, according to the API semantics.
To answer your question, since the physical location of memory is the same for CPU and GPU for Intel, the fact that you are not calling didModifyRange doesn't affect your app in your particular case. There still might be some corner cases where it might not work, due to some caches not being flushed or something similar, but in general, it will work. If you had a machine with an AMD GPU, that would not be the case. Without didModifyRange you just wouldn't see the CPU changes on GPU.
